# Word for the realisation that you are alive?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

To put it into context, a sudden moment where you notice the world around you and the things you have experienced... and how amazing life is.

Comment: That sounds like a moment of enlightenment: the action or state of attaining or having attained spiritual knowledge or insight

Comment: Sounds like you're having an _epiphany_.

Comment: Not a one word: "the sense of being alive". *When you "feel alive", you have a "keen sense of your environment"*.

Answer (score 3):

You're having an ***[epiphany](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epiphany)***:

> A moment of *sudden* and great revelation or *realization*.

Comment: Ugh, just realised this suggested in the comments already. Why don't people put answers up though, it really fits IMO...

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word and it's in French, but this phrase was the first thing that came to mind:

**Joie de vivre** (*English translation: ​joy of living*) is a French phrase often used in English to express a cheerful enjoyment of life; an exultation of spirit.

Answer (score 1):

'Conscious' may be another word.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a term you might like, "[anagnorisis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anagnorisis)". It was used in Ancient Greek Tragedy to define a moment where the hero made some sort of important discovery.

To put it simply, the word means,

> the critical moment of recognition or discovery

so it would be a great word to use to describe a moment when you realize that you're alive

Answer (score 0):

The terms *[self-awareness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-awareness)* or *[mindfulness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness)* may apply in certain contexts, though both terms are rather broad by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

> **Self-consciousness/awareness**: awareness that one exists as an
>   individual being.
>
> **Qualia**:  individual instances of subjective, conscious experience.
>
> **Memento Mori**: "remember (that you have) to die" is the medieval Latin
>   theory and practice of reflection on mortality.
>
> **Solipsism**:  the theory that only the self exists.

Answer (score 0):

***[Cognizance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cognizance)***:

> - Knowledge or ***awareness***.

And also:

> - Attend to; take account of.

These two definitions combined work for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Word for the realisation that you are alive?
>   *Awakening*.

From ["Awaken"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/awakened):

- To become aware of something (intransitive verb); "She awakened to the fact that everyone was staring at her expectantly."
- To cause (someone) to become aware; alert or enlighten (transitive verb); "The slam of the door awakened him to the realization that she was never coming back, and that he now faced an uncertain future of coping with the holes in his life that she left behind."